# ArialLabelledBy is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accessibility

I have a control called _message. using sapui5 i am trying to create a text label and get the element by id using jQuery and set the arialLabelledBy for that element. 
When i turn on the narrator and click/hover or get the blue outline around th element that is selected it doesn't read anything.

Am i doing something wrong?

```
   var oLabel = new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Message screen reader"});
    this._msgid = this._message.getId();
    var textmsg = jQuery("#" + this._msgid);
    textmsg.addAriaLabelledBy(oLabel);
```

Comment: What browser/OS/screen reader? Do you have an HTML example (you provided script)? Can you see the attribute being added to the element in the inspector? Are you adding the attribute to a control that gets focus?

Comment: Show the resulting HTML please

Answer (score 0):

> `var oLabel = new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Message screen reader"});`

1. you have created an HTML `label` for a non control element. You should create a TextView element.
2. You have created a label object, but have not inserted this object in the DOM.

You have to insert the object in the DOM before making the association with `addAriaLabelledBy` to reference an existing object. (see [`placeAt`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html#placeAt) for instance)